# How can i get the arrray months to be displayed in the console?

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] months = File.ReadAllLines("Month.txt");
    Console.WriteLine(months);
}
```

Comment: [**`foreach`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx)

Comment: Are you trying to display all months? You might then eventually be better of by defining an enum instead of reading from a file.

Comment: Or perhaps just `string[] names = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames;`

Answer (score 4):

Just iterate through each item in the collection using a [`foreach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) loop :

```
string[] months = File.ReadAllLines("Month.txt");
foreach(var month in months)
{
     Console.WriteLine(month);
}
```

Other approaches might include a plain [`for`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) loop :

```
for(var m = 0; m < months.Length; m++)
{
     Console.WriteLine(months[m]);
}
```

Or if you needed them as a comma-delimited string, you could use the [`String.Join()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) method :

```
// Yields "January,February,March..."
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(',', months));
```

Answer (score 1):

Or without `Foreach` by using [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string[] months = File.ReadAllLines("Month.txt");
string str = String.Join("\n",months);
//Or string str = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, months);
Console.WriteLine(str);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: For being Environment aware you might want to use Environment.Newline instead of "\n".

Answer (score 0):

```
    string[] months = File.ReadAllLines("Month.txt");
    string str =string.Empty;
    foreach (var item in months)
    {
        str = item + ";";
    }
    Console.WriteLine(str);
```